# Why my bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo return an empty list?

Tags: bitcoin-cli, peer-discovery

I am running `bitcoind` and it is updating blocks as follows:

[image: running bitcoind]

However, when I have run `bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo`, it only returns an empty list, but not peers connected. So if there is no peer connected to my node, how can my `bitcoind` node update and download blocks from internet?

[image: bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo]

Comment: Is it possible that at the time you issued the RPC command you accidentally had no connections, but at other times you do?

Comment: Was this call made at the same time the log lines were produced? Is your bitcoin-cli connected to the same instance of `bitcoind` that you were reading the logs of?

Comment: Yes, my `bitcoin-cli` is connected to the same instance of `bitcoind`, and when I restarted `bitcoind` after several days, rerunning `getpeerinfo` command shows the peer information. I think @PieterWuille was right that maybe it had accidentally no connections at that time.